# How to invalidate Spring SessionAttributes

Tags: java, spring, session

everyone. I have a question about Spring SessionAttributes annotation. Right now I'm using it to transfer data within a workflow that involves several pages. The data is contained in a modal attribute and in turn stored in a SessionAttribute (with an annotation in front of the controller). So I have this problem, if I use

```
sessionStatus.setComplete();
```

when I'm leaving the workflow, the session gets cleaned. But if I leave the workflow without completing it, the data get stuck in the session. I tried

```
sessionStatus.setComplete();
```

and

```
request.getSession.invalidate();
```

and re-initialize the model attribute, none of them get the job done. The data in the session is still there when I restart the workflow.

Any idea how to clear the data? Or is there any work around so that I can use something other than session to store the data in the workflow.

Comment: `But if I leave the workflow without completing it` Is there a reason you don't want to complete it?

Comment: I'm only considering the scenario that user not leaving the workflow properly, like hit the back button on browser multiple times, or used a link on the nav bar.

Comment: i have a similar problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407052/spring-lifecycle-issue-the-annotation-sessionattributes-makes-session-attribut